# $a_k$ are close when arithmetic mean is close to the geometric mean

Tags: inequality

Consider a sequence of $n$ nonnegative numbers $\{a_k\}$ along with their arithmetic and geometric means:

$$A = \frac{1}{n} \sum a_k$$

$$G = \left ( \prod_k a_k \right )^{1/n}$$

Given that $A$ and $G$ are close in the sense that:

$$\frac {A - G}{A} = \epsilon > 0$$

show, for some fixed $\epsilon$, that the individual $a_k$ are bounded above and below as:

$$\rho_0 \leq a_k/A \leq \rho_1$$

where $\rho_0, \rho_1$ are roots of the equation:

$$\frac{x}{e^{x-1}} = (1- \epsilon)^n$$

**My attempt:**

It is possible to show that the roots of the above equation are such that: $\rho_0 \in (0, 1]$ and $\rho_1 \in [1, \infty)$ and that $\rho_0 = \rho_1 = 1$ only when $\epsilon = 0$. It is also easy to show that the LHS of the above equation is increasing on $[0, 1]$ and decreasing on $[1, \infty)$ so it is equivalent to show that each $a_k$ is such that:

$$\frac{a_k/A}{e^{a_k/A - 1}} \geq (1-\epsilon)^n = \left(\frac{G}{A}\right)^n$$

I tried to simplify by considering the situation in which all $a_k$ are equal (in which case $A= G$) and then transferring $\delta > 0$ from some $a_i$ to some $a_j$. In this case, $A$ remains constant, but $G$ decreases. So if I can show that the LHS decreases less than the RHS then maybe I can go after an induction on the number of terms $a_k \neq A$. But I am struggling to show the claim, even in this simple base case.

I am looking for some vague hints on how I might show the above inequality.

Comment: (Not certain if this works out, but it's my first guess): Try showing that if $a_1 < \rho_0$, then $G(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \leq G( a_1, \frac{n-a_1}{n-1} , \ldots, \frac{n-a_1}{n-1} ) \leq G(\rho_0, \frac{n-\rho_0}{n-1} , \ldots, \frac{n-\rho_0}{n-1} ) < G$, where the function is the geometric mean, and the arithmetic mean is normalized to 1.

Comment: Thanks, the comment was helpful, but not exactly how I solved it eventually. See the answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

I'll only show the lower bound since the upper bound is similar.

By construction:

$$\frac{\rho_0}{e^{\rho_0 - 1}} = \left (\frac{G}{A}\right)^n = \prod_i\frac{a_i}{A}$$

Without loss of generality, assume $a_1 \leq a_i \, \forall \, i$. Note that for a fixed arithmetic mean, the geometric mean of a set of non-negative numbers is maximized when all terms are equal. So, we may bound the above RHS by:

$$\prod_i\frac{a_i}{A} \leq \frac{a_1}{A} \left (\frac{\beta}{A}\right )^n$$

where $\beta$ is such that: $((n-1)\beta + a_1) / n = A$. Simplifying the above we have that:

$$\frac{\rho_0}{e^{\rho_0 - 1}} \leq \frac{a_1}{A} \left(1 + \frac{1-a_1/A}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$$

But the second term on right is bounded above by $\exp(1-a_1/A)$ with equality iff $a_1 = A$

Since this holds for the smallest $a_i$ it must also hold for the all $a_i$. This is precisely what we were trying to show in the original attempt above.